# Remove script tag from parsed html with simple html dom parser

Tags: php, parsing, web-scraping, xml-parsing, html-parsing

I am using simple html dom parser with php to parse a link using below code.

```
foreach($html->find('div#ProductDescription_Tab') as $description)
{
    $comments = $description->find('.hsn_comments', 0); 
      $comments->outertext = ''; 


     echo $description->outertext;

}
```

This gives me the parsed data along with javascript "script" tags. How can I remove these script tags?

Answer (score 1):

Ok So i figured out myself just use Advanced Html Dom library its totally compatible with simple html dom & by using it you will get much more control. Its very simple to remove what you want from parsed html. For Ex.

```
//to remove script tag
$scripts = $description->find('script')->remove;

//to remove css style tag
$style = $description->find('style')->remove;

// to remove a div with class name findify-element
$findify = $description->find('div.findify-element')->remove;
```

https://sourceforge.net/projects/advancedhtmldom/